# Changing style of lines in GeoGraphics

Tags: geographics

I have a list of coordinates and want to draw lines on a map between these coordinates. These lines may either be paths (GeoPath) or just straight lines (Line). The problem I am facing is that I want to draw two lines between each pair of coordinates, to represent going back and forth, and these two lines should be a different color. An example is this image, https://docplayer.nl/docs-images/69/61593419/images/9-0.jpg, but, as explained above, in my case the two parts of the road should be able to have a different color as well.

I was hoping to be able to draw one line between every pair of coordinates, with this line being divided vertically into two colors, to represent the two lines. I know you can draw a line with two colors, but I only know how to do this with a horizontal division, e.g.:

`Graphics[{Thick, Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 1}}, VertexColors -> {Red, Green}]}]`

My solution now is to place two lines close to each other, like this:

`Graphics[{{Thick, Red, Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 1}}]}, {Thick, Green, Line[{{0, 0.005}, {2, 1.005}}]}}]`

but this gives problems if you have to connect multiple lines on a map, as, dependent on the slope of the line, these two might overlap:

`Graphics[{{Thick, Red, Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 1}}]}, {Thick, Green, Line[{{0, 0.005}, {2, 1.005}}]}, Thick, Red, Line[{{2, 1}, {2.2, 2}}]}, {Thick, Green, Line[{{2, 1.005}, {2.2, 2.005}}]}}]`

An example set of coordinates to tryout with (intersections on the A16 road in the Netherlands):

`{GeoPosition[{51.874635307793, 4.570947724013}],GeoPosition[{51.857146702404, 4.59740340268}], GeoPosition[{51.700838317451, 4.649052525846}], GeoPosition[{51.645409145412, 4.692113271953}], GeoPosition[{51.581462919313, 4.724696855408}}`

Comment: So you would like that line and a line parallel to it in a different colour, is that correct?

Comment: @CarlLange Yes, two parallel lines of different colors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make a parallel line by doing the following:

```
makeParallel[pts_, dist_] :=
 GeoDestination[#[[1]], {dist, 
     GeoDirection[#[[1]], #[[2]]] - 
      Quantity[90, "AngularDegrees"]}] & /@ 
  Partition[pts, 2, 1, {1, 1}, Last@pts]
```

used like:

```
line = {GeoPosition[{51.874635307793, 4.570947724013}], 
  GeoPosition[{51.857146702404, 4.59740340268}], 
  GeoPosition[{51.700838317451, 4.649052525846}], 
  GeoPosition[{51.645409145412, 4.692113271953}], 
  GeoPosition[{51.581462919313, 4.724696855408}]}

GeoGraphics[{
  Blue,
  Line@line,
  Red,
  Line@makeParallel[line, 300]
}, GeoBackground -> None]
```

[image]

Basically, we get each pair of points in the list and calculate their normal (`GeoDirection` minus 90 degrees), then translate each point by the normal and some arbitrary distance `dist` with `GeoDestination[pt, {dist, normal}]`.

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot! For a lot of lines your function does a perfect job. For some of the sets of coordinates the result is not fully correct and the lines intersect (e.g. for ```{GeoPosition[{52.350495664864, 4.96232904696}], GeoPosition[{52.328341223555, 4.913557669966}], GeoPosition[{52.338032031812, 4.842070619223}], GeoPosition[{52.397547735184, 4.845495736403}], 
 GeoPosition[{52.42344948688, 4.877876809137}]}```. Do you know why this happens, I do not fully understand why it does not work in this case?

Comment: Sorry, yes, this happens because of the direction of the line segments (going left rather than right). I'm not sure right this second how best to solve that - I'm sure there's a simple way, but my head isn't screwed on today! I hope the answer so far is helpful :)